# How do I discover properties of an IPropertyBag?

Tags: com, reverse-engineering, directshow

Besides a dictionary attack, what can I do?

I'm trying to find out what properties do DirectShow filters have. I know one of the properties is FriendlyName (that's the only one MSDN mentions), so I tired searching for it through quartz.dll with a hex editor thinking that names of other properties might be nearby, but apparently quartz.dll does not contain the string "FriendlyName".

(No, IPropertyBag2 is not available.)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12129961/32453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, quartz.dll *does* contain the string "FriendlyName", but it's in Unicode (UTF-16), not ASCII. From a quick look, quartz.dll also tries to get properties "CLSID" (VT_BSTR), "Merit" (VT_I4), "FilterData" (VT_UI1|VT_ARRAY).

Answer (score 0):

There might be additional properties, but it is unlikely. Those powerder WDM kernel drivers expose DriverPath property. Others might have additional properties mapped from additional registry keys. Anyway, you are not going to find anything interesting there...