# who can tell me something about IPropertyBag::Read?

Tags: c++, directshow

In directShow, except "FriendlyName",what other properties can i get from the IPropertyBag::Read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"CLSID", "FriendlyName", sometimes "DevicePath". There might be filter-specific properties as well. Nothing else is there.